# Anyone start to doubt, whether their cited page numbers are correct? And how to improve?

Tags: citations

Anyone start to doubt, whether their cited page numbers are correct?

I seem to run to this constantly. Check e.g. BlahBlah 1994, p. 285-287, see it's okay.

(time passes)

"Am I certain they're the correct pages? That I haven't e.g. mistyped what should've been 284-287 or something."

How can one improve on this issue?

Comment: Are you asking for an academic solution or a psychological one?

Comment: (1) Use a reference manager. (2) Stop caring about such trivialities. The page numbers are usually the least important part of a reference. They could be completely wrong and you most likely could still find it. If this really is your biggest concern about your publications, then you don't have any serious concerns at all.

Comment: @Roland I'm concerned, because they're required. From a practical point of view I understand the idea that it's more important that the information can be found, than whether the citation position is absolutely correct. Because it's not difficult to mistype e.g. few page numbers off etc., if you're not careful.

Comment: @BryanKrause Both. I suffer a bit from a psychological need to "be sure" and recheck after rechecking, because I don't trust my memory.

Comment: In peer-reviewed journals, the production department usually will check your references. But, provided that you use due diligence, this is really not something to waste time and effort on. A reference manager that imports references from online databases will help.

Comment: @Roland I've rationalized the "effort" differently. It takes less time for one person to check that they're accurate, than for all the readers to have to recheck, where the information is, if the referenced page numbers are off. So it saves "global time", if the publication is flawless. Yes. Zotero makes it a bit easier.

Comment: I believe you are severly overestimating the number of readers who do this.

Comment: Honestly, I cannot remember when I typed page numbers of a reference by hand. Databases and citation managers do the job very well.

Comment: @mavavilj But nobody checks just to check. If they open up the book to page 284, it doesn't take that long to figure out the material (by name) is on page 285

Answer (score 1):

If you make it a habit to put the page citations into your document or your lab notebook or wherever you do scratch work at the very time you are looking at the page you will know that the citations are correct.

Comment: Good suggestion.